# What means foo()(bar) in go and how it works?

Tags: go, syntax, semantics

In `auth0` QuickStart tutorial for Golang I had found this piece of code:

```
router.Handle("/api/private", middleware.EnsureValidToken()(
    http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        w.Write([]byte(`{"message":"Hello from a private endpoint! You need to be authenticated to see this."}`))
    }),
 ))
```

Then I had simplify it to this form:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write([]byte(`{"message":"Hello from test"}`))
}

func preHandler() func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {

    log.Println("in preHandler")
    return func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return check(next)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/test/", preHandler()(http.HandlerFunc(handler)))
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}
```

But I can't figure out how is working and what is meaning of this piece of code `preHandler()(http.HandlerFunc(handler))`

Thnx for help!

P.s.
I tried to find answer in google but nothing. I just want to find out how it works

Answer (score 3):

The statement

```
http.Handle("/test/", preHandler()(http.HandlerFunc(handler)))
```

has three [function calls](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Calls) and a [type conversion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions). I'll explain what's going on by splitting the one statement into four statements:

```
f := preHandler() // f is function with type func(next http.Handler) http.Handler
h := http.HandlerFunc(handler) // type conversion to http.HandlerFunc
hw := f(h)   // call f with h, result is an http.Handler
http.Handle("/test/", hw)  // register the handler
```